# .htaccess: Redirect url if "string" in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want redirect **old** url to **new** url `[301]`

> Old url :

```
http://www.name.com/one/?page=2
http://www.name.com/two/?page=5
http://www.name.com/three/?page=1
```

> New url :

```
http://www.name.com/one/page/2/
http://www.name.com/two/page/5/
http://www.name.com/three/page/1/
```

How can redirect url if **?page=X** contain in url and move to **/page/X/** ?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Also, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: I read this topics but not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^?]+)/\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/page/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect **/foo/?page=123** to **/foo/page/123/**